# How to save and delete any name or entity in Worklight?

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

Hi im new to the IBM Worklight.
can anybody please tell me how to save a name/entity and delete it in IBM Worklight.
im not getting the concepts of sql adapters too. please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about User Preference Methods?

User preferences are composed of two attributes, a user preference
key and a user preference value. The user preference key is a string
that uniquely identifies the user preference.

The preference are saved in the Worklight data base. In order to use them the user must be authenticated (so the preference could be connected to a single user).

You have those methods to work with them:

```
WL.Client.setUserPref(key, value, options)
WL.Client.setUserPrefs({key1:value1, key2:value2, …}, options)
WL.Client.getUserPref(key)
WL.Client.deleteUserPref(key, options)
WL.Client.hasUserPref(key)
```

The SQL Adapter

The adapter enables you to execute parameterized SQL queries and stored procedures, in order to retrieve or update data in the database.

You call the procedure from the client with parameters (if needed) and the adapter query a database. The result set is sent to the client as a JSON object.

Comment: i was expecting your reply, thank you. well for now i need a normal input text(say user name) to be stored in sql db. and later i will be getting the data from the api and store the json data in user name created in sql db. soo please could you tell me both methods. thank you.